# How many options exist to attach a semi-compliant button to USB cables?

Tags: usb

To boot Qualcomm Android phones into low-level bootloader, "EDL cables" are used which have an integrated button to short D+ with GND. To be effective, the button needs to be pressed at some point during power-on.

Integrating a button into a USB cable isn't something covered by the USB standard. However, shorting D+ with ground seems to be tolerated by most devices at least. I assume, this has been specifically chosen as the least harmful violation of the standard.

I wonder, is this the only reasonable choice? Would e.g. shorting D- with GND also be a viable hack?

Comment: You should indicate which kind of USB connector you are targeting. On some of them, there are additional pins (e.g. ID on micro-B, CC on type C) that could be helpful in implementing non-compliant devices, with some level of compatibility with compliant hosts.

Comment: shorting D+ with ground is a legal USB bus state called "Reset" (assuming FS/HS bus mode). There is no other "options" for Android bootloader.